# How does Lisp "prog" work in this example?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm a beginner in lisp and I need somebody to explain to me how the `prog` form works, step by step. What is the initial value of l1 ? Nil ?

The problem outputs T if the list has an even number of elements on the first level, nil if not.

```
(defun nr_par (l)
  (prog ((l1 l))
    ciclu
    (cond
      ((null l1) (return T))
      ((null (cdr l1)) (return NIL))
      ((null (cddr l1)) (return T))
      (T (setf l1 (cddr l1))
         (go ciclu)))))
```

On console:

```
(nr_par '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8))

T
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The program is straightforward, but not very idiomatic lisp (it is rather imperative instead of functional). Step by step goes as follows.

`prog` uses a series of variable bindings, in this case, `l1` is assigned the value of `l` initially. Then, a series of statements in which  a loop starts (again, not very lisp idiomatic).

This type of loops use a tag (`ciclu`) and a goto instruction (`go`), again, not recommended, but it is there. After that, the `cond` checks a series of cases. When the list is empty (`null`), you return true, in other cases, you check if the length is even or odd, and return the value in consequence.

In the case that the list is longer than one or two elements (neither of the cases is null), the `l1` list is adjusted to point to the next of the next element of itself (the `cddr` function).

Finally, the `go` function turns the program back to the `ciclu` tag.

The program will finish when any of the `cond` clauses is met, returning either `T` or `NIL`.

Comment: 'not very idiomatic lisp' - actually it's how a lot of Lisp code looked like in the 60s and 70s.

Comment: today's example is as idiomatic as it gets within a common style of lisp "exercises" (I always assume that the requirements were like "write such-and-such function using PROG, COND, GO, CD[D]R and nothing else". It seems that no teacher in the world would accept `(evenp (length list))` as a solution).

Comment: Or even `(reduce #'(lambda (v _) (not v)) LIST :initial-value t)`

Answer (score 2):

See [PROG in CLHS](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_prog_.htm): `L1` is *var*, `L` is *init-form*,  so the initial value of `L1` is the value of `L`.

Answer (score 1):

As [the CLHS page for `prog`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_prog_.htm) says, it does three things: lets you have local vars and initialize them; lets you have tags as in `tagbody` and use `go`; and lets you use `return` as inside a `block` named `NIL`:

```
(defun nr_par (l)                     
  (prog ((l1 l))                           ; local binding(s)
    ciclu                             
    (if (null l1)       (return T))        ; return
    (if (null (cdr l1)) (return NIL)) 
    (setf l1 (cddr l1))  
    (go ciclu)))                           ; go

(defun nr_par1 (l)                         ; directly equivalent
  (labels ((ciclu (l1) 
             (if (null l1)       (return-from ciclu T)) 
             (if (null (cdr l1)) (return-from ciclu NIL)) 
             (ciclu (cddr l1))))
    (ciclu l)))

(defun nr_par2 (l)                         ; also equivalent
  (do ((l1 l (cddr l1)))
      (NIL)                                ; while T ...
    (cond
      ((null l1)       (return T))
      ((null (cdr l1)) (return NIL)))))
```

Function call is a glorified `goto` after all, isn't it?

See also [Longest decreasing sequence in Lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8597157/longest-decreasing-sequence-in-lisp/14316848#14316848) for an example representing several mutually-recursive functions hand-compiled into a `prog` with a bunch of `GO` statements.